# htaccess : stop subdirectory auto redirecting to root index

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Well, I am sorry if this question already exist but I have failed to find it even after severe searching.

Suppose a part of my site directory is such -

```
/index.php (root)
/appdir/app1/index.php
```

**But when I try to access app1/index.php it automatically redirects to root index.php.** I couldn't find possible reason for this. My .htaccess looks like this :

```
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase only requires in localhost alias 
RewriteBase /

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^(.*)_(v|V)[0-9\.]+\.(css|png|gif|jpe?g|html?|swf|js)$ $1.$3

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Is there way to access my app index.php or stop redirecting to root directory?
Thanks for your appreciation.

N.B: Full root htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/D1tvXh76

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #Does not rewrite file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #Does not rewrite direcotry
```

For better understanding how `mod_rewrite` works read the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: Sorry. now it falls for redirects loops.

Comment: @neo-nant There might be a redirection in `index.php` itself. replace that with simple script for testing purposes/

Comment: No, just RewriteBase / edited, it was RewriteBase /alias (for localhost). But I have tested with test index file but now it makes "302 found" redirects.

Comment: Edited full root .htaccess added. Please have a look in it.

Comment: @neo-nant well, at first, remove `#Does not rewrite file` and `#Does not rewrite direcotry`, they are odd and were written for you. there might be problems with parsing it.

Comment: ok, now the problem narrow downs to that: /appdir/app1/ shows if it doesn't contains index.php file!

Comment: @neo-nant Well, you can try to comment or delete `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`. I thought you wanted to display directory too.